# Adding additional string to message body (swift)

Tags: email, swift, uitextfield, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I got my email working fine.  The only thing i need to do is add an additional string to my message body.  For example, I want to add Name: and textfield to my message body. Something like this.

Name:  John Smith

Phone: 566-654-6577

Email:  Smith@smith.com

Right now, the message body only show the following.

John Smith

566-654-6577

Smith@smith.com

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI


class EmailTableViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!


    func appendTextFromTextField(string: String, textField: UITextField) -> String {
        return string + textField.text + "\n \n"
    }


    @IBAction func SendEmailButton(sender: AnyObject) {


        var fields: [UITextField] = [name, phone, email]
        var messageBody = ""

        for f in fields {
            messageBody = appendTextFromTextField(messageBody, textField: f)
        }

        var emailTitle = "Interface Information"
        var toRecipents = [""]
        var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
        switch result.value {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
            println("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
            println("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
            println("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }




}
```

Comment: `for f in fields{ZzZ}`: Need to be rewritten to fit your needs.

Comment: how would you rewrite it?

Comment: messageBody + "Name:" + name.text + "\n\nPhone:" + phone.text etc, or add theses "hard written values" into your method (array/dictionary).

Comment: Got it.  That was easy.  Thanks.

Comment: var messageBody = "Name: " + name.text  + "\n\nPhone: " + phone.text + "\n\nEmail: " + email.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `for` loop and try replacing your method with this one:

```
@IBAction func sendEmailButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var messageBody = "Name:\(name.text)\nPhone:\(phone.text)\nEmail:\(email.text) "
        var emailTitle = "Interface Information"
        var toRecipents = [""]
        var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` and `zip2` functions to do something like this.

```
let fields: [UITextField] = [name , phone, email]
let fieldNames : [String] = ["Name", "Phone" ,"Email"]

let messageBody = reduce(Zip2(fields,fieldNames),"") { body,zipped  in
    let (field,fieldName) = zipped
    return body + fieldName + " : " + field.text + " \n\n "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 
     var fields: [UITextField] = [name, phone, email]
        var messageBody = ""

```
    for f in fields {
        messageBody = appendTextFromTextField(messageBody, textField: f)
    }
```

with:
        var messageBody = ""
        let addOn:String = "name: (name.text)\nphone: (phone.text)\nemail:(email.text)\n"
        messageBody = messageBody + addOn

Also, I am not sure why you have a tableViewController. If you dont put a table in your storyboard you will get a runtime error

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I guess my original code was a bit more complicated then it need to be.  This definitely simplify it.