# Xcode Add multiple String Message Body

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm attempting to send an Email with an additional string. I was able to find a related link in StackOverflow: [Adding additional string to message body (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282442/adding-additional-string-to-message-body-swift). I need assistance to add an additional string with user's typed text message after phone number.

Example:
Name
Email
Phone Number
Message

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailAddressfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phoneNumberfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var subjectfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var requestfield: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func Send(sender: Any) {

    var SubjectText = "Prayer Request: "
    SubjectText += subjectfield.text!

    var _: [UITextField] = [nameField, phoneNumberfield, emailAddressfield]

    let toRecipients = ["st.johnamechurch@att.net"]

    let MessageBody = requestfield.text!

    let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mc.setSubject(SubjectText)
    mc.setMessageBody(MessageBody, isHTML: false)
    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

    self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail Cancelled")

    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
        print("sMail Saved")

    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Mail Sent")

    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Mail Failed: %@", [error?.localizedDescription])

    default:
        break
    }

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    self.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Don't you just need to append to `MessageBody` (should be lowercase)?

Comment: you can use `let messageBody = requestfield.text! + "ADDITIONAL BODY TEXT"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to append the information in your message body string, same as what you did for `subjectText`. Your `send` function should be like:

```
@IBAction func send(sender: Any) {
    let subjectText = "Prayer Request: " + subjectfield.text!
    let toRecipients = ["st.johnamechurch@att.net"]

    var messageBody = requestfield.text!
    messageBody += "\nName: " + nameField.text!
    messageBody += "\nPhone No.: " + phoneNumberfield.text!
    messageBody += "\nEmail: " + emailAddressfield.text!

    let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mc.setSubject(subjectText)
    mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

    self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: OP: Note the correct case of the variables and methods.